# How to better crop and paste an image in PIL

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to crop an avatar and place it in a given location in another image using python pil.
Here is the output of what I have so far:
[image]

And here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
import textwrap

text = "Creating Twitter Cards dynamically with Python"
background_image = "data/obi-pvc.png" # this is the background
avatar = Image.open("data/avatar.png")
font = "data/fonts/AllertaStencil-Regular.ttf"
background = Image.open(background_image)
background_width, background_height = background.size
avatar.convert('RGBA')

## DO NOT change below this line!!
save_name = f"{text.lower().replace(' ', '_')}.png"
#textwrapped = textwrap.wrap(text, width=text_wrap_width)

# crop avatar 
width, height = avatar.size
x = (width - height)//2
avatar_cropped = avatar.crop((x, 0, x+height, height))
width_cr, height_cr = avatar_cropped.size
# create grayscale image with white circle (255) on black background (0)
mask = Image.new('L', avatar_cropped.size)
mask_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
width, height = avatar_cropped.size
mask_draw.ellipse((0, 0, width, height), fill=255)
# add mask as alpha channel
avatar_cropped.putalpha(mask)


draw = ImageDraw.Draw(background)
font = ImageFont.truetype(font, font_size)
draw.text((offset,margin), '\n'.join(textwrapped), font=font, fill=color)

x, y = avatar_cropped.size
margin = 40
# left top
position_tl = (0 + margin, 0 + margin)
position_tr = (x - margin - width_cr, 0 + margin)
position_bl = (0 + margin, y - margin - height_cr)
position_br = (x - margin - width_cr, y - margin - height_cr)

background.paste(avatar_cropped, position)
background.save(f"data/output/{save_name}")
display(background)
```

The avatar should fit within the circle. I can't seem to really figure out how to apply the positioning. Thanks

Here is the avatar:
[image]

Comment: the code does not work and looking for this value:  text_wrap_width. what is the value of text_wrap_width?  please also share the image file avatar.png. thanks.

Comment: @jose_bacoy I added the avatar. the text_wrap_width can be commented out for now. I am using jupyter notebook. The code works. Thanks